# Odd looking tableview in storyboard Xcode8?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

After upgrading to XCode 8, my static tableview look very odd. Any ideas why this is happening? It looks almost fine on the simulator, but the storyboard looks odd. It seems like the cells are too small, but they are the right size on the simulator and the constraints are just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's Design Issue of **Xcode 8** .
Some time your view size change etc.... thats all **xcode 8 design issue** .

we send apple developer to this issue and  Waite for new xcode and we hope solve this issue in new one  .